# How run two different threads simultaneously in pyqt

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a situation where i need to start two threads one after the other. I tried the following code snippet, here i could able to start the Thread12 but not able to start Thread2. How can i start both....? 
How to start 2 threads one ofter the other...?

**Code snippet**

```
class Thread1(QtCore.QThread):

    Thread1Signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super(Thread1, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        print 'Thread1 started'
        While True:

            #some statments
            if Condition:
                Thread1Signal.emit('Yes')
            else:
                Thread1Signal.emit('No')

class Thread2(QtCore.QThread):

    Thread2Signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super(Thread2, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        print 'Thread2 started'
        While True:

            #some statments
            if Condition:
                Thread2Signal.emit('Yes')
            else:
                Thread2Signal.emit('No')

class MainClass(QtCore.QObject):

    MainSignal1 = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    MainSignal2 = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainClass, self).__init__()   

        Threadinstance1 = Thread1()
        Threadinstance1.Thread1Signal.connect(MainSignal1)

        Threadinstance2 = Thread2()
        Threadinstance2.Thread2Signal.connect(MainSignal2)


   def start(self):

       Threadinstance1.start()
       Threadinstance2.start()                #Thread2 never starts.

def signal1called(s):

    print s


def signal2called(s):

    print s

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = AtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    temp = MainClass()
    temp.MainSignal1.connect(signal1called)
    temp.MainSignal2.connect(signal2called)
    temp.start()
    sys.exit(app.exec()_)
```

Comment: Are you sure your test case has your threads running long enough for you to see the signals emitted? You are starting your threads before you start the event loop. Are they actually running in loops emitting signals well beyond the event loops starting or might they be finishing too quickly ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will be using `QRunnable` and `QThreadPool`, something like this:

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtCore import QThreadPool, QObject, QRunnable, pyqtSignal

class WorkerSignals(QObject):
    result = pyqtSignal(int)

class Worker(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, task):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()

        self.task = task
        self.signals = WorkerSignals()

    def run(self):
        print 'Sending', self.task
        self.signals.result.emit(self.task)

class Tasks(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Tasks, self).__init__()

        self.pool = QThreadPool()
        self.pool.setMaxThreadCount(1)

    def process_result(self, task):
        print 'Receiving', task

    def start(self):
        for task in range(10):
            worker = Worker(task)
            worker.signals.result.connect(self.process_result)

            self.pool.start(worker)

        self.pool.waitForDone()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import  sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Tasks()
    main.start()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: you can create as many `Worker` classes as you want, subclasssing from `QRunnable` instead of `QThread`, then calling from `Tasks`

Comment: you mean we cant use `QThread` for my query...? Instead i need to use `QRunnable`. Whats the diff bewteen `QRunnable` and `QThread`

Comment: You can, but if you want them to run one by one, you can use `QThreadPool`, that takes `QRunnable`'s but not `QThread`'s, or send an **processEnded** signal from each `QThread` and connect it to a slot that starts the next `QThread`

Comment: actually i need both the threads start simultaneously.... so, taught of starting one after the other. but not to start one after completing the other.

Comment: starting `QThreads` simultaneously shouldn't be a problem, re-check your actual code if you can't, you can still use `QThreadPool` though, just skip the `self.pool.setMaxThreadCount(1)` part

Comment: i changed `self.pool.setMaxThreadCount(1)` to `self.pool.setMaxThreadCount(2)` since i have two definition to run in two threads...