# GUI hangs until all threads are created

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyside

I have created a GUI Scraper(Qt and Python) which runs with multiple threads .. the GUI seems to hang until all threads are spawned.. i am running the scraper with like 200-300 threads.. after all threads are created the GUI is responding.. is there a way to stop the application from not responding while creating the threads..

I have created a New Python Thread in Main thread then call tempthread in below code which is in a QThread Class

```
def tempthread(self):
        self.tempt = threading.Thread(target=self.spawn)
        self.tempt.daemon=True
        self.tempt.start()

def spawn(self):

        global noofthreads
        for xd in range(0,noofthreads):
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.startscrape)
            t.daemon = True 
    t.start()    
            tarray.append(t)
            t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.waitthreads)
            t1.start()
def waitthreads(self)
        for t in tarray:
            t.join()

        self.message.emit("Program Execution Completed")
```

Comment: add a processevents in there every 20 threads

Comment: It is bad idea to create a lot of threads. There are no real tasks that requre it. It is preffirable to create thread pool. In perfect case number of threads should be equal to number of CPU cores.

Answer (score 0):

When you need lots of threads it is better to use thread pool. I found that [there is python binding for that](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qthreadpool.html), so definitely you should try this. Here is [similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13909749/1387438).

Sadly there is no python binding for [QtConcurrent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtconcurrent.html). It is nice API but it uses templates and it is badly documented.