# QtThreadPool and data model

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt

I am learning multithreading in Qt an I am facing an issue with `QThreadPool`.

I have a `MainController` class that contain a `QThreadPool`.
This class also has a specific method `processDirectory` to initialize threaded processes:

```
class MainController():
    def __init__(self, model, view):
        [...]
        self.pool = QtCore.QThreadPool()
        self.pool.setMaxThreadCount(2)

    def processDirectory(self, dirpath):
        [...]
        # Create a directory worker
        dirrunnable = DirRunnable(dirpath, extSelected, self.model.dirMgrModel)

        # Send worker to thread pool
        self.pool.start(dirrunnable)
```

Then I have a signal/slot connection in a widget witch catches a new directory to launch the `processDirectory` method.

I have race condition because sometime the code will work and sometimes it won't.

So my question is:
Is permitted to send new worker to the thread pool from a method of a given class?
In this case how would you handle the creation of the new workers and the sending to the the thread pool?

In my case, what happen to my `dirrunable` object when the method `processDirectory`?
Will the pool keep the object in its context?

Since I have problems, my idea at the moment is to created another thread that would contain the pool and that would receive the directory path thru a queue to create the workers in that thread.
But it seems so insane that I feel I am missing big something here!

Thank you for your help!

Btw: The error that I get and that I can't understand no matter what I read on the internet:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QVector<int>'
(Make sure 'QVector<int>' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

Comment: As for the error: the message is pretty clear if you ask me. Have you looked up what [qRegisterMetaType()](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType-2) does?

Comment: Yes I have, but I can't figure out a logical connection between this function and my threading implementation. I don't understand where this `QVector<int>` is used. For example, in this solution, it's not used anywhere: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13909749/882697

Comment: Info provided is insufficient: the error is central to this problem, and indicates that the issue arises while attempting to connect a signal to a slot. Since the code does not show any connections being established, it is impossible to tell what the problem is. Please re-read your post and put yourself in another reader's shoes: would you understand your post? Please provide the missing info and clarify the post accordingly.

Comment: I realize that there is something missing in my question. Actually this error didn't appeared when I had no threading implementation. That is why I was focused on the threading. I need to look a bit more at my code to debug this. But I have no clue at all at the moment. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: A good way to debug is to produce a minimilistic example program that displays the problem (the shortest possible running program with the problem). If that doesn't cause you to find the problem, posting that minimal working example will provide us with enough information to debug.

Comment: Yes that is what I am going to try. I also had another idea: I have a table model that is updated in the thread. So the int vector that is sent maybe in this model. I need to check that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Finally found my bug. It was the model actually the update of the model from the thread that was messing everything up. I found a guide line stating that in most cases it shouldn't be done. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone reaches this post someday. The problem was that you are not allowed in Qt to put a model in a thread. So I solved the problem using signals to update the model in the main thread.